# Corrupted theme for certain applications

Tags: themes, ambiance, gtk3

I am facing a problem related to corrupted gtk theme for certain applications. My default theme is Ambiance under Unity. It works fine for most applications like Chrome, Firefox, Nautilus, etc. However, for certain applications such Gnome tweak tool, Ubuntu Tweak, etc. the gtk theme is completely black and dark. That is the background window color, making viewing the window text very difficult.

This is happening with Gnome shell also. I have tried resetting gnome and Unity settings, reinstalling light themes, but it didn't work.

[image: A snapshot of how Ubuntu Tweak looks.]

Also, note that I do not face this issue while using other themes such as Adwaita.

Comment: could you add a screen shot?

Comment: @Alexandre I am not aware how I can add pictures to this post. I will post one if you tell me how to post.

Comment: @Alexandre Yes, I got it. I have uploaded a snapshot.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: This bug is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/943682

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is no longer valid after upgrades.